# Я не могу понять как вставить экземпляр объекта класса в список другого класса

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

```py
def add(items):

    item = input('Введите название товара: ')
    items.purchase_item(item)
    print(item + ' в корзине')

def get_money(items):
    print(items.get_item_list())

class CashRegister:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__item_list = []
 
    def purchase_item(self, item):
        self.__item_list.append(item)
```

Comment: Прокомментируйте пожалуйста что здесь что, отформатируйте вставки кода в вопросе и расскажите какой результат получаете и какой хотите получить

Comment: line 9, in purchase_item
    self.__items.append(item)
AttributeError: 'CashRegister' object has no attribute '_CashRegister__items'

Comment: ссылка на всё задание https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-beginners/thread2870483.html#post15700381

Answer (score 1):

Да вроде у вас всё работает, только не реализована функция `get_item_list`, я добавил её и протестировал код:

```
class CashRegister:
    ...
    def get_item_list(self):
        return self.__item_list

cr = CashRegister()
add(cr)
get_money(cr)
```

Вывод:

```
Введите название товара: test
test в корзине
['test']
```

Comment: Получаю такую ошибку: line 9, in purchase_item
    self.__items.append(item)
AttributeError: 'CashRegister' object has no attribute '_CashRegister__items'

Comment: Нашел ошибку, банальная опечатка. Мучаюсь с классами. Пока с ними только сложнее. Вот ссылка на всё задание если интересно cyberforum.ru/python-beginners/thread2870483.html#post15700381

Comment: @АлександрАфанасьев А как вы обращаетесь к этой функции? Подозреваю, что вы не создаёте экземпляр класса, посмотрите у меня пример, как нужно правильно вызывать методы экземпляра класса.